# Image resizing AWS Lambda with threads

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I have 20000 images in S3 Bucket. I want to resize all of them using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). For doing this I am downloading the image in the `tmp` folder of Lambda and then uploading it back to [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

I want to optimize it so I implemented threading in it. My code is working fine when I am using 15 threads, but when I am using more than 15-16 threads it is creating issues like connection pool is full. I would like to mention that I have explicitly taken care of waiting for the termination of already running threads.

What can I do to optimize the code? If more threads can be created then whats the best way of creating threads inside Lambda?

Comment: You implemented threading... where?  In the code calling the Lambda function externally, or in the Lambda function itself?  If the latter, I don't think you've actually accomplished much in the interest of efficiency.  If the former, *what* connection pool is full?  Unrelated, be sure you delete your files from `/tmp` after processing, or you have another surprise coming.

Comment: I implemented threading in the lambda function itself. And yes I have taken care of cleaning up the  /tmp  folder. Is there any workaround to improve this.

Comment: Improve what, exactly?  The general idea behind Lambda is one invocation = one task.  If your processing is CPU intensive, your runtimes are pretty much going to be linear -- processing two files in two threads in one invocation will take about the same amount of instance time as processing one file each in one thread in two invocations... meanwhile, doubling the memory will reduce the runtime by approximately half, because the CPU cycles available to each invocation are directly proportional to the memory you allocate.  (For no reason other than that's just how they designed it.)

Comment: I wanted to improve the time it is taking to do the entire processing. So you mean to say that rather than using threads I should be  invoking lambda functions everytime, I mean for each image I should have a different lambda function. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  Each concurrent invocation runs in an independent container, and you can have up to 1,000 containers running at any moment in time wihin your account without any pre-provisoning -- Lambda will just keep starting them up as demand indicates.  If the function is invoked when there are recently-used, idle containers still alive, it will usually pick one of them and reuse it, starting at the handler (which is why cleaning up `/tmp` is important). Otherwise the containers are destroyed within minutes.  But you only pay while they're actually running invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the info,  one more thing I would like to ask, considering the fact that I have 20000 images is there any chance that I will run into some error as we can have maximum of 1000 lambda functions concurrently processing. I mean what if all of the 1000 lambda functions are processing and I invoke some more lambda functions.

Comment: You should get errors on the invoke call, which you can back off and retry, although the limit can be somewhat soft if the system heuristically decides that the burst seems legitimate (e.g. not a runaway/loop). This was why I originally asked the probably strange-seeming question about *where* you were using threads.  In the code were you are invoking the individual Lambda function, you could use a pool of workers to invoke the Lambda functions synchronously -- the API call will block until execution completes and then the worker could invoke another until there are no more requests to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call a lambda method 20k times passing the filename it needs to work with... don't need to wait. each lambda call will process each file. you can have 20k threads that way.

you can create a rule, so when a new file is in S3, a lambda method is called. but the first batch will need to be processed manually.

Comment: be careful... or at the end of the month the bill will be high :)

Comment: I am aware of that but I am looking for a better solution.